# How to integrate jar files in Spring Boot using web.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working on integrating a `.jar` file, which is basically a Spring application with a `web.xml`, in a Spring Boot application.

I got a `.war` file of a Spring Boot application in which I need to deploy the `.jar`.

My Spring application has a few context listeners implemented that have been registered in the `web.xml` which I want to register in the Spring Boot App.

I've tried to run the Spring Boot app by placing the `web.xml` in the WEB-INF folder, however it ends up overwriting the entire project configuration instead. It lets the listeners initialize but does not let the `war` file run.

Removing/not using the `web.xml` results in the Spring Boot `war` file running, but the context listeners don't get initialized and result in a null pointer exception.

Relevant portions of `web.xml`:

```
<listener><listener-class>org.XXX.CustomContextListener</listener-class</listener>

...

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Log4jConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.XXX.Log4jConfigurationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Log4jConfigurationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ConfigureLog4j</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Context Listener:

```
@WebListener
public final class CustomContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void contextIntialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent){}

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {}
}
```

Is there a way I can register my listener to Spring Boot app or use web.xml for jar files in Spring Boot application without overriding any Spring Boot configurations?